# How to quickly select everything (including the parentheses themselves) between two parentheses in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, mouse-click, double-click

For example, when I double-click a sequence of characters between two parentheses, I would like for all the characters to be selected when I use Microsoft Word.

What settings can I set so a click action such as double-click or triple-click or something else will select everything between two parentheses?

Comment: I know of no such setting. A macros should be able to do it and you could set a keyboard shortcut to activate it. It seems that just clicking before the the opening parenthesis, and then shift-clicking after the closing one would be about as easy.

Comment: great and smart solution, many thanks! @CharlesKenyon

Comment: It is true that the basic functionality of Word cannot achieve this requirement, you need to record a macro to quickly select the content in two parentheses, or there may be plugins on the Internet to implement it.